# EACCES permission denied on android 11 with MANGED_EXTERNAL_STORAGE granted

Tags: android, android-11

I was trying to read from a file I pushed to **external app private folder**

[image]

In my manifest I also declared all 3 storage related permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and also I already granted all files access permission in the app setting page:

[image]

However, when I tried to read the file via File api, it still fails with permission error:

```
val file = File(context.getExternalFiles(null)).absolutePath, "test.json")
val fileStream = FileInputStream(file)
```

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.jetbrains.handson.mpp.myapplication/files/test.json: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
> at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:492)

My understanding is that since its a app private folder , the app should always has access to it when permission is granted. However, it does not work. And I dont believe its a scope storage issue since I already granted access to all files, not just media.

Thanks!

Comment: Your screenshot shows `test.json`. Your source code shows `test.config`. Those are not the same.

Comment: @CommonsWare sorry thats a typo, let me fix it, but in the code its reading test.json

Comment: You do not need to request permissions in manifest and you certainly do not need all files access reading from that app specific directory.